# JQuery click a state becomes active after submit it's not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an SVG map. When someone clicks on a state say, "California" the state turns yellow and a form appears. This is working fine. The code that turns the state yellow when clicked.  This code is in the head.

```
$("#map > svg > path").each(function(i){
$(this).css('fill', '');
});
$('#' + data.name).css('fill', '#e8f600');
```

After the form is submitted, if validation sees a problem, it will go back to the same page.  The state that was active turns #fff instead of staying as #e8f600.

Forgot to add -  I've been trying to get this to work but no luck.

```
<?php if ($_POST) { ?>
  $('#' + data.name).css('fill', '#e8f600');
  <?php echo ('#e8f600'); ?> 
   <?php } else { ?>
    <?php echo ('#fff'); ?> 
     <?php }  ?>
```

I've been trying to find a solution for hours but can't seem to fix it.

My question,

How can I code this to keep the state active after posting on the same page?

Comment: Same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551785/jquery-populating-select-box-but-after-post-options-disappear), post the active state to the server and then check for the presence of the posted value on reload and use it if its there.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work.... already tried it.

Comment: Add the code that tries to do that to the question then. Also what fails, does it fail to post to the server or is it the reload that's the problem?

Comment: If I knew what fails I would fix it.  The question is what would you do with the code above to keep the state active.

Comment: You need to read a book or search for how to debug php and javascript. Many browsers have javascript debuggers and there are UIs that can debug php. Unless you post your complete attempt we can't help you any further.

Comment: On page submit or refresh all css goes back to initial state. To keep the state active use cookie to store the active state. On submit or refresh check for the cookie value and make the state active based on that value

Comment: No don't want to use a cookie.  PHP and jquery should be able to handle this

Comment: Where's the javascript/html client code that populates the html form element with the active value?

Comment: Its a SVG map.  It gets overwritten with the first code block above -  $("#map > svg > path").each(function(i){
$(this).css('fill', '');
});
$('#' + data.name).css('fill', '#e8f600');

Comment: Then that's your problem. You need an html form input element as they are what get submitted. It can be of type "hidden" if you don't want it visible.

Comment: Can you give me an example? For example, how would I assign the active map color to a form element?